# Execure a random command from .txt file?

Tags: server, cron, twitter

I have a Ubuntu server, and I'm trying to print a Twitter quote using the app "twidge". So I made a list of tweets on a .txt file.
I want to print one tweet (per line) from that file and send it to Twitter via twidge (or what ever other method was possible).

I can print a random phrase with `shuf`:

```
shuf -n 1 /var/www/tweets.txt
```

and it works. It sends me back one of the tweets, but, it does not send it to Twitter, even if the "in line" phrase is a command. i.e:

```
twidge update "bla bla bla"
```

It just prints on the screen, but don't send it to Twitter. I tried turning the .txt to .sh, but don't work...
any idea?

by the way, i want to use it with crontab, something like this:

```
15 * * * * shuf -n 1 /var/www/tweets.txt
```

Comment: Have you tried `twidge setup` and entered the authorisation key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write a short script which performs the operation, eg `/var/www/post.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
shuf -n 1 /var/www/tweets.txt | twidge update
```

Make it executable with `chmod +x post.sh`, and add it to `crontab`.

Comment: Why a script?. It's only a one line command, looks like an extra complication to me. Why not adding the command directly to crontab?.